# Could not load file or assembly 'NLog.Web.AspNetCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nlog, .net-6.0

I'm upgrading my solution from .NET 5 to .NET 6 and getting the error at runtime

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NLog.Web.AspNetCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'NLog.Web.AspNetCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c'
> at MyApp.Program.CreateHostBuilder(String[] args)
> at MyApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in ..\MyApp\Program.cs:line 18

I'm using `NLog 4.7.15`, and `NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.15.0` nuget packages. The versions did not change during upgrade. As soon as I upgraded all my projects in the solution, I started getting that error at runtime, **both on Windows and macOS**. As soon as I switch back to .NET 5 the error goes away. I tried upgrading to `NLog 5.0.0-rc2` and I get the same error but just  `Version=5.0.0.0`. Downgrading the packages had no effect either.
I'm also using JetBrains Rider.

I'm clueless how to approach this problem. I've searched the web and haven't found any working solutions.

Comment: As the error says, the NLog assembly could not be found; The first step would be to ensure the .dll files exist within the development/output directory (and are being copied when compiled)

Comment: Everything should be loaded through Nuget package manager. I've verified that the package is present and the correct assembly version is referenced. Is there anything else I can do? The bin folder only has .dll files created for the project and doesn't have nuget package .dll files in there.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/765

Comment: Yep that was me there too. That fixed the problem. Will follow up with .NET team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be a bug in .NET 6

Having this property in the project file was causing the issue

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>false</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Removing it solved it. Not the best solution as I need to use that property. Will have to open up an issue with .NET team.

EDIT: Created an issue with them: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/68720